# Mixed integer and string in strace output in write syscall

Tags: assembly, x86, att, strace

I want to call a write syscall from 32-bit assembly, the code i'm using right now:

```
.section    .rodata             # read-only data
msg:
    .ascii  "hello"             # char array called "msg" (no null character)
len:
    .long   5                   # length of "msg"


.section    .text               # actual runnable code
.globl      _start
.type       _start, @function
_start:
    movl    $4, %eax            # syscall number into eax (4 is write)
    movl    $1, %ebx            # argument number 1 into ebx (stdout)
    movl    $msg, %ecx          # argument number 2 into ecx
    movl    len, %edx           # argument number 3 into edx
    int     $0x80
    
    movl    $1, %eax            # syscall number into eax (1 is exit)
    movl    $0, %ebx            # argument number 1 into ebx (exit code)
    int     $0x80
```

To compile it i first invoke the GNU assembler and then the linker:

```
as --32 main.s -o main.o
ld -m elf_i386 main.o -o main
```

It compiles and works properly, printing the string "hello" to the console, but when i use strace to "see" the write happen, i get following output:

```
execve("./main", ["./main"], [/* 86 vars */]) = 0
strace: [ Process PID=22529 runs in 32 bit mode. ]
write(1, "hello", 5hello)                    = 5
exit(0)                                 = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

I'd like to know what causes the third argument to be 5hello instead of 5.

Comment: Nothing, the `hello` in there is the actual output of your program. Redirect the output of either strace or your code so they don't get interspersed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing, the `hello` in there is the actual output of your program. Here is what is happening:

1. strace intercepts the write syscall
2. strace prints the call name and the arguments: `write(1, "hello", 5`. Note this goes to `stderr`. For some reason it doesn't print the closing `)` yet.
3. the `write` syscall gets executed, thus `hello` is printed to `stdout`.
4. strace again needs to get control so it can print the return value, which it does along with the closing parenthesis giving the `) = 5`.

In your case both `stdout` and `stderr` refer to the same terminal. Redirect the output of either strace or your code so they don't get interspersed.

Comment: I can't actually believe i've missed that, thank you. i'll accept your answer in 3 minutes

Comment: I believe the `strace` hook will output the arguments first ahead of calling the system call (logically, as the call is free to modify them), then upon return it does finish the output with return value. Meanwhile the write did it's job with "hello".

Comment: @Ped7g: That doesn't fully explain why `strace` doesn't wait to print the `) = retval`.  The reason is that system calls can block, so it prints the call stuff before the call, and the return stuff after the call.  This is easily visible by running `strace sleep 1`.  strace will even print extra stuff when a system call is interrupted by a signal (e.g. if you `^z` during the `nanosleep` or `pkill -WINCH sleep` to send it a signal that won't do anything).

Comment: @Jester: I think it holds off on printing the `)` so interrupted system calls are more obvious in the output (which could be important for use-space that chooses not to restart an interrupted system call with the same args).  Or maybe it has something to do with the fact that some system calls (like `nanosleep`) have output pointer args?